# Visual Studio Locks

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I don't really know how to describe my problem but sometimes it locks and shows a preview like box (as in screenshot) and then I can not edit my project. Escape key does not work. What is that and  how can I overcome thank you.

[image]

Comment: This is a bug with the GTK# docking in Visual Studio for Mac 8.x. There is no fix in the v8 version. Visual Studio for Mac 17.x has a native macOS UI where this bug does not occur.

Comment: Thanks @MattWard I appreciate. I will change the version.